# Is it safe to print 0 to a file?

Tags: c++, operating-system, std, filestream

Is it safe to print 0 (as unsigned char) into a file? Will that mess up (might the filesystem rely on NULL being file termination? )

I am using a `std::ofstream` object to write to the file.

Comment: It is okay, you will put a byte in the file

Comment: You may want to open the file in `ios::binary` mode.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I thought the `std::ios::binary` only handled EOL characters?

Comment: The `std::ios::binary` mode is to inform the I/O system not to perform any translations on the data.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Ah, well I had it opened in that mode already anyways. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can write `0` to a file. To close it, just close the file handle.

Answer (score 2):

You can write whatever you want to the file, the characters you send are interpreted into the specific character encoding of that file.

Only ofstream:close() will close a file

Answer (score 2):

You can write anything to the file, as long as you don't assign 0 to a pointer/variable in your code.

Answer (score 2):

It's just an ASCI character and eof() does'nt take 0 as a null character